# In what sense were virtual particles confirmed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, virtual-particles

[This wiki article states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum#Historical_understanding) (at the end of the Historical Understanding subsection): "This has far reaching consequences on the "emptiness" of space between particles. In the late 20th century, so-called virtual particles that arise spontaneously from empty space were confirmed."

**Questions:** Is it reasonable to interpret this statement to say that the existence of virtual particles was confirmed, in the same sense that Rutherford confirmed the existence of atomic nuclei, and JJ Thompson confirmed the existence of the electron, etc...? IF so, what specific experiments/observations led to the scientific consensus that virtual particles exist in nature, and are more than just a useful mathematical description (let's avoid positivist rabbit holes if possible please :) ).

Comment: I would guess they are talking about the Casimir effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would describe that statement as misleading at best.

The end of the introduction of the Wikipedia page for [Virtual particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) more accurately describes the consensus opinion.

> The accuracy and use of virtual particles in calculations is firmly established, but as they cannot be detected in experiments, deciding how to precisely describe them is a topic of debate. Since it is possible to perform quantum field theory calculations completely absent virtual particles being referenced in the math used, as seen in lattice field theory, then it is believed virtual particles are simply a mathematical tool.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this is that quantum-mechanical predictions which do not take into account the (undetectable) presence of virtual particles or photons differ significantly from those measured in experiments- for example, in the case of the *Lamb shift*. When the influences of virtual particles or photons are properly accounted for, the agreement between theory and experiment then becomes better than one part in a million.

In addition, there are measurable physical effects (the *Casimir effect* for example) which have no explanation at all if those virtual photon or particle pairs are not included in the model.

Please let me know if this represents to you a "positivist rabbit hole", whatever that might be.